# How to show that $\int_0^2 |x-1|^{-a} dx = 2\int_0^1 x^{-a} dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $a<1$. How to show that
$$\int_0^2 |x-1|^{-a} dx = 2\int_0^1 x^{-a} dx?$$

Could someone please help? Thank you in advance!

${\bf EDIT:}$ It is
$$\int_0^2 |x-1|^{-a} dx =\int_0^1 (1-x)^{-a} dx +\int_1^2 (x-1)^{-a}dx.$$
Taking $y=x-1$ in the second integral, we have
$$\int_1^2 (x-1)^{-a}dx =\int_0^1 y^{-a} dy$$
and taking $y=1-x$ in the first one
$$\int_0^1 (1-x)^{-a} dx =-\int_1^0 y^{-a} dy = \int_0^1 y^{-a} dy.$$
It is correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Split the left-hand integral into two integrals either side of $1$.

Comment: @J.G. you mean $\int_0^2 |x-1|^{-a} dx = \int_0^1 (1-x)^{-a} dx +\int_1^2 (x-1)^{-a}dx$?

Comment: That's it, yes.

Comment: How to get the desired result?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Shaun is right, I'm afraid. Help us help you, so to speak. For starters, now you've understood what decomposition helps, edit into your question an effort to show each piece is itself equal to $\int_0^1y^{-a}dy$. You'll need a different substitution for each piece.

Comment: @J.G. question edited.

Comment: Well done, this is correct (after a small edit on my part).

Comment: @J.G. thank you for the help and sorry for my mistakes in asking the question.